# Jenkins findbug threshold issue

Tags: jenkins-plugins, sonarqube, findbugs

While running sonar from jenkins job for one of my project I am facing issue ,

**" Can not execute SonarQube analysis: Can not execute Findbugs with a timeout threshold value of 1200000 milliseconds: TimeoutException -> [Help 1]"**

I tried to google it for help but every where I found only solution .
**"You can increase the timeout: Settings > General Settings > Java > Findbugs > sonar.findbugs.timeout"**

In my office jenkins installed as a service and I am not able to find the above mention path,
Any one would please give any details what would be the possible cause of this issue.
What could be the solution and if the solution is like above which I mention then please guide me where I can find path or please let me know that if I need to update any config file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should find that setting in Sonarqube, not in Jenkins. Check here: [image: this]

Comment: thanks @carlo for pointing me in correct direction, Would you please let me know what would be the possible reason of this issue as only increasing default time not working for me.

Comment: I have the same problem. Were you able to resolve @Amit ? I've increased the timeout to 3600000 ms, which is 1 hour and I keep seeing the below message..
<br>
01:48:45.618 [WARNING] [JOURNAL_FLUSHER] WARNING Journal flush operation took 126,162ms last 8 cycles average is 72,125ms
<br>
Any pointers?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to update timeout value of **FindBugs**. Follow the below steps:

On the SonarQube server : Go to **Administration** -> Choose category **Java** -> **FindBugs** tab -> increase the **Timeout** value.

Find the below image for reference : 
[image]